# Reading "merged" string from two resource files

Tags: c#, resx

The story is the following:

1. An application is supplied by 2 not embedded resource files (resource.resx, resource.user.resx)
2. The "Resource.resx" has two strings: **Type** *"Möbel"*, **Name** *"Stuhl"*
3. The "Resource.user.resx" has string: **Name** *"Sessel"*

the application has the following line

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", Resource.Type, Resource.Name)
```

The result should look like:

> Möbel: Sessel

in common case the "Resource.resx" can be supplied by dosens of strings. What I want to archieve is that each **Resource.ResourceStingId** istruction implements the following logic:

Return value of **ResourceStingId** from "Resource.user.resx" if exists, if not the value of **ResourceStingId** from "Resource.resx"

Appreciated solution is an automated one.

Thanks!

Comment: Basically you would have to encapsulate access to both resources files in a class that will deal with your priority rule.

Answer (score 0):

I have came to a conclusion that resource files are not the entities designed for such a trick.
Investigating the problem found some iteresting topic about customization of ResXFileCodeGenerator ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27473/Enhanced-Resource-File-Code-Generator-Type-safe-Fo  ),
but did not started digged at that direction because decided that the investments ill take more than a benefit.

Have also wrote a dummy method that merges the files accordantely defined rule.

```
private static void MergeResource()
    {
        var userDocument = XDocument.Load(@"resource.user.resx");
        var userData = userDocument.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "data");

        var originalDocument = XDocument.Load(@"resource.resx");
        var origData = originalDocument.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Name == "data");
        var notMatchedData = origData.Where(oe => userData.All(ue => ue.Attribute("name").Value != oe.Attribute("name").Value));

        foreach (var data in notMatchedData)
            userDocument.Root.Add(data);

        userDocument.Save("Resource.resx", SaveOptions.None);
    }
```